# asp.net quotes problems in data binding

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, quotes

i'm trying to binding a variable data to a input control as the value of the property,but the vs2010 throw a warning:"validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional):Attribute values must be enclosed in quotation marks."

can anyone tell me how to fix it?

here is my code:

`<input type="button" id="btn_jump" runat="server"
onclick=<%#"javascript:window.location.href='Default.aspx?var=" + m_id + "'" %> value="jump"/>`

i've tried these below but get an error:"Server tag is not correctly formatted"

```
<input type="button" id="btn_jump" runat="server"
onclick="<%#"javascript:window.location.href='Default.aspx?var=" + m_id + "'" %>" value="jump"/>

<input type="button" id="btn_jump" runat="server"
onclick='<%#"javascript:window.location.href='Default.aspx?var=" + m_id + "'" %>' value="jump"/>
```

here is the correct solution:

method 1:

```
btn_jump.Attributes.Add("onclientclick","javascript:window.location.href='Default.aspx?var=" + m_id + "'");
```

method 2:

```
<input type="button" id="btn_jump" runat="server"
onclick='<%#"javascript:window.location.href=\"Default.aspx?var=" + m_id + "\"" %>' value="jump"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should use `OnclientClick`**. Do the below approach.

```
<input type="button" id="btn_jump" runat="server"
onclientclick='redirect(<%#Eval("m_id")%>)' value="jump"/>


function redirect(id) {
  location.href = 'Default.aspx?var=' + id;
}
```

**OR use Eval placeholder**

```
<input type="button" id="btn_jump" runat="server"
onClientClick='<%# Eval("m_id", "location.href=Default.aspx?var={0}") %>' value="jump"/>
```

**Or add onclientclick Attributes from code behind**

```
btn_jump.Attributes.Add("onclientclick","javascript:window.location.href='Default.aspx?var=" + m_id + "'");
```

Comment: thank you very much,this method can works well.but i have five button to redirect to different page,so i need to add five javascript function,this is too complicated.and as my way,the page is works except an warning.

Comment: location.href link without single quote cannot redirect,and my variable "m_id" is not a database field but a codebehind variable, so we cannot use eval() function.